# Google BOT visit and site languages

Tags: seo, lang

In my site, I have different languages in the same page, I mean, that if you select your lang, the the same file, show you the content in your language.

According to your browser language, my site load the content in that language, and in the HTML tags I add:

(In Spanish lang for example)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="**es**" xml:lang="**es**">
```

for Google bot detect the language, but I have a problem. For example, in Google.es (Google Spain) the Google bot is indexing English content, I think that it is because, the google bot browser or config is in english.

I want to know how to tell to Google bot, that in Spain have to save spanish content, in Brazil, portugues content etc..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need an own URL for each language version.
2. For users: You should offer an language switcher (link to all translations on each page), using `hreflang` attribute
3. For bots: You should link the translations of each page with `<link rel="alternate" href="…" hreflang="es" />` (and so on)

If you site is example.com, and (nearly) all pages are translated, you could use the following URL design:

- `example.com/en/…` (for English)
- `example.com/es/…` (for Spanish)
- …

If someone visits `example.com/`, you could redirect to the language version that is configured in the browser (but if someone visits a specific language version, don't redirect to another language!).